# Can I block HTTP request sended from winlogon.exe and lsass.exe?

Tags: http, inject, malware, winlogon

You know there are malwares injected into system process like winlogon.exe and lsass.exe, and communicate with outside server with HTTP traffic. Is it a reasonable rule to block HTTP traffic send from winlgon.exe and lsass.exe? Any false positive possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Blocking such traffic sounds like dealing with the symptom instead of removing the cause. Fix your system or better even get a system that is less vulnerable to such infections.

Comment: Winlogon.exe send http traffic, it give me a clue that there maybe malware that AV do not detect.  A advance threat.

Comment: So replace that file (whatever it does) with a clean one you take from a non infected system. If it is infected (_you_ claim that) then you have to fix that. Or do you also deal with a bleeding  cut by pumping blood into the body? No, you take care to clean and close the cut.